# Cross Validation is Feature Selecting in Classification

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S06JpVoNaA0&index=4&list=PLxXnVFYbQ9rnPMGqMHiyjguvj4iY9R6O4) from the well-famed Intro to Stat Learning course on doing cross validation in feature selecting.

The professors said that we should form the folds before doing any model fitting and feature selecting . They also said that in each split, we may end up with a different set of "best predictors"

My question is, if that is the case, how can we determine the overall best predictors for future use. In other words, if I have a new set of data, how do I know which predictors I should use?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question isn't about programming so isn't a good fit for this site. You'd be better off asking at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same set of features for future use. Yes there is a trade-off that the features selected might change with time. But usually ones goes with the features selected before. ***But important thing is that the initial data used for feature selection should be good enough with sufficient number of samples so that it reflects almost all cases of the problem.*** If this is the case, usually, the features selected would not change that much for a new test data as well.